# Is Java's LinkedList optimized to do get(index) in reverse when necessary?

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, linked-list

I've been working on some ways to optimize LinkedList's. Does anyone know if the Java default doubly-linked LinkedList class is optimized to do `get()` operations in reverse? 
For example:

```
// Some LinkedList list that exists with n elements;
int half = list.size() / 2;
list.get(half + 1);
```

Would the call to `list.get(half + 1)` optimize the search and go in reverse since it is a doubly-linked list? It would make more sense to do the search from the end and go towards the center if you know the element is in the second half of the list.

I know using `get(index)` is `O(n)` time and that you should use an iterator when traversing a LinkedList, but I am just curious.

Comment: It's right there in the third paragraph of the javadocs (second paragraph in Java 7): `Operations that index into the list will traverse the list from the beginning or the end, whichever is closer to the specified index.`

Comment: Just note that from the performance POV, most uses of LinkedList are a mistake anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is. You can inspect the source code yourself: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.entry%28int%29

`LinkedList#get(int)` is implemented as just

```
return entry(index).element;
```

where `entry` is a private method. `entry`'s definition is:

```
private Entry<E> entry(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index: "+index+
                                            ", Size: "+size);
    Entry<E> e = header;
    if (index < (size >> 1)) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++)
            e = e.next;
    } else {
        for (int i = size; i > index; i--)
            e = e.previous;
    }
    return e;
}
```

As you can see, it counts down from the end if index is greater than the midpoint of the list.